# How to locate a computer (Mac) on an intranet?

Tags: networking

I am curious. We have an intranet here at my place of work, the organization is quite big and I am pretty sure it's not a single network (e.g. it's a typical level 3 LAN or even several LANs). We're a small subgroup in the organization sitting in the same office space and there is a Mac Mini that's connected to a huge HDTV on the wall showing "useless stats" all day long.

I know for a fact that it's on the Windows network domain, and I in fact have credentials (my own) to authenticate with the domain.

Problem is, I don't know the address or hostname of the Mac and which e.g. remote desktop protocols it supports.

I would like to login remotely with my username and password (Windows domain network which we use) and just put something else on the HDTV, temporarily. A motivation poster :P Nobody will get hurt.

I would want to do it without doing the technically completely unnecessary round of asking *people* about its hostname, address etc. They're all network buffs, and I am very tired of asking them questions. To practice my networking skills, I want to pull this off on my own -- `finger`, some careful port scan -- what to throw in the toolbox and how to go about it? The host is connected somehow, I can probably distinguish it from others because it's a Mac through some heuristics?

Comment: I'd be very careful doing this at work – "nobody will get hurt" is relative. (If anything, _you_ will get hurt once the admins find out.)

Comment: I have no intentions of hacking anything, I need to locate the Mac, optionally building immediate network topology, and enumerate network services the Mac provides. It's 2 meters away from me, and I am surrounded by the admins, I just want to see what capabilities networking tools may have that save administrators' time. You seem to be envisioning some sinister scheme plotting, but that is far from the truth here.

Comment: Potentially you would have to scan the network (e.g. `nmap`) and more often than not it's easily going to get you into trouble. You could also try to watch for broadcasts (e.g. `Wireshark`) which, as it usually requires promiscuous mode, again is something a lot of network admins don't really like on normal computers. As it is a Mac it might be running Bonjour so you could go for something like [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB2MG_4.6.0/com.ibm.ips.doc/concepts/gx_gv_bonjour_service_discovery.htm).

Comment: It might have its MAC address on a label on it. Have you got your CV up to date?

Comment: I am not a crook! Seriously though, I have talked to our admins about this, just so that things are in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *nmap* with a very lax time-frame, something like

```
nmap -T1 -O 192.168.0.0/24
```

where I assumed your broadcast domain is *192.168.0.0/24*, if not pls change accordingly.

The [nmap manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) states:

> **-T paranoid|sneaky|polite|normal|aggressive|insane** (Set a timing template) .
>
> While the fine-grained timing controls discussed in the previous section are powerful and effective, some people find them confusing. Moreover, choosing the appropriate values can sometimes take more time than the scan you are trying to optimize. So Nmap offers a simpler approach, with six timing templates. You can specify them with the -T option and their number (0-5) or their name. The template names are paranoid (0), sneaky (1), polite (2), normal (3), aggressive (4), and insane (5). **The first two are for IDS evasion**. Polite mode slows down the scan to use less bandwidth and target machine resources. Normal mode is the default and so -T3 does nothing. Aggressive mode speeds scans up by making the assumption that you are on a reasonably fast and reliable network. Finally insane mode. assumes that you are on an extraordinarily fast network or are willing to sacrifice some accuracy for speed.

where I added a bold typeface to stress the reason for the choice *-T1*.

Also,

> **-O** (Enable OS detection) .
>
> Enables OS detection, as discussed above. Alternatively, you can use -A to enable OS detection along with other things.

If you decide to go this way, go grab yourself a six-pack, you will have ample time to drink it all before the task above completes.

Comment: Thank you. This (nmap) should suffice for my needs. I've read about the tool and how it works (heuristics no small part of it) and this gives me all kinds of pointers on how to learn from there. I've used nmap before, but it always slipped between higher priority tasks and I never paid it the attention I know see it deserves.